# What is the difference between lambda abstractions?

Tags: haskell

What is the different between those expression:

```
z n = n + 1
```

and

```
z = \n -> n  + 1
```

?

Comment: @RobinZigmond The first one is a perfectly valid function definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second declaration uses a simple binding `z = ...`, so it is affected by the monomorphism restriction. The first one uses a function binding `z x = ...`, so it is not affected.

Apart from that, there is no difference.

Adding an explicit type signature would remove even the difference about the monomorphism restriction, which would not apply to any of the declarations. The same holds if we disable the MR in GHC using a flag or `LANGUAGE` pragma, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are no behavioral differences, but depending on optimization settings, there could be small differences in performance.

As an example, in the `base` library, in `GHC.List` we see the following:

```
-- The lambda form turns out to be necessary to make this inline
-- when we need it to and give good performance.
{-# INLINE [0] lengthFB #-}
lengthFB :: x -> (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
lengthFB _ r = \ !a -> r (a + 1)
```

(Copied from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html but there are plenty of other examples just in `base` or in `containers`). Specifically the two different forms may have differences in the arity of the function and affect inlining differences.

The difference could be more pronounced if there is additionally a `where` clause in the definition. In the absence of the let-float optimization, the second form means that all invocations of the function share a single instance, but in the first form different invocations may create separate instances. Again, this is depending on optimization settings and usually with `-O` GHC will produce identical code.